# Is $Spin(N)$ a subgroup of $SU(N)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Is $Spin(N)$ a subgroup of $SU(N)$? If so, how can we embed $Spin(N)$ into $SU(N)$? I would love to find a representation where both $Spin(N)$ and $SU(N)$ act faithfully and see explicitly how the embedding is done. For example, $SO(N)$ can be embedded easily in $SU(N)$ by consider the fundamental representation.

Comment: It doesn't even make sense *a priori* to ask whether $\mathrm{Spin}(N)$ 'is' a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(N)$, since they aren't immediately realised in a common overgroup.  For the embedding, do you really mean to take the *same* $N$?  Do you want the embedding to be algebraic, or just smooth?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your comment. My motivation was that $SO(N)$ is a subgroup of $SU(N)$ while $Spin(N)$ is the $Z_2$ extension of $SO(N)$. I was then wondering whether $Spin(N)$ can be viewed as a subset of $SU(N)$. It would be nice to see an argument that it is true or false explictly.

Comment: @Lam LSpice possibly suggests that you make use of the word "isomorphism", which turns out to be a useful concept.

Answer (score 25):

$\def\Spin{\mathrm{Spin}}$The spin group has a representation $S$ called the [spin representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation), which has dimension $2^m$ for $N=2m$ or $2m+1$. It is irreducible for $N$ odd and splits into two complex conjugate representations $S_+ \oplus S_-$ for $N$ even, with each of $S_{\pm}$ being of dimension $2^{m-1}$. These are the smallest representations of $\Spin(N)$ which do not factor through $SO(N)$. So, once the power of $2$ exceeds $N$, the spin group will not embed in $SU(N)$.

This leaves us to analyze $1 \leq N \leq 6$, and $N=8$. Each of these has some [special form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Accidental_isomorphisms).

$\Spin(1)$ is the trivial group. Clearly, this embeds in $SU(1)$.

$\Spin(2)$ is the circle group $\mathrm{R}/\mathrm{Z}$. Note that $SO(2)$ and $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$ are isomorphic as abstract groups, but the map $\mathrm{Spin}(2) \to SO(2)$ is the double cover. Clearly, this embeds in $SU(2)$.

When $N=3$, the spin representation $S$ is two dimensional and gives an isomorphism $\Spin(3) \cong SU(2)$. So, in particular, $\Spin(3)$ embeds in $SU(3)$.

When $N=4$, the representations $S_+$ and $S_-$ are two dimensional, giving an isomorphism $\Spin(4) \cong SU(2) \times SU(2)$. Conveniently, this embeds into $SU(4)$ via the representation $\mathbb{C}^2 \boxtimes 1 \oplus 1 \boxtimes \mathbb{C}^2$. We cannot use just one of the two $SU(2)$ representations, as the individual projections have kernels. Particle physicists call working with $\Spin(4)$ in the form $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ the "spinor helicity formalism". If you talk to the sort of particle physicists who care what the signature of spacetime is, you'll want to know that $\Spin(3,1) \cong SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

When $N=5$, $\dim S = 4$. Indeed, this $4$-dimensional vector space can be identified with a $2$-dimensional quaternionic vector space and $\Spin(5)$ is the group of $2 \times 2$ unitary quaternion matrices. So $\Spin(5)$ embeds into $SU(4)$ (and also into $SU(5)$.)

When $N=6$, we have $\dim S_+ = 4$ and gives an isomorphism $\Spin(6) \cong SU(4)$. So $\Spin(6)$ embeds into $SU(6)$ with lots of room.

When $N=7$, we have $\dim S = 2^3 > 7$, so $\Spin(7)$ does not embed in $SU(7)$. It does embed in $SU(8)$, though.

When $N=8$, we have $\dim S_+ = \dim S_- = 8$. Unfortunately, the corresponding maps $\Spin(8) \to SU(8)$ have kernel. Indeed, there are three maps $\Spin(8) \to SO(8)$, related by the triality symmetry of $\Spin(8)$, and each of them has a central two element group as kernel. So there are interesting maps $\Spin(8) \to SU(8)$, but no embeddings. The composition $\Spin(7) \to \Spin(8) \to SO(8)$ for one of the nononbvious maps $\Spin(8) \to SO(8)$  is the embedding of $\Spin(7)$ I referenced above.

Once $N \geq 9$, the spin representations have dimension much larger than $N$.

Comment: This is a great answer!  Is it obvious that, because the natural $8$-dimensional unitary representations of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ have kernel, there is *no* faithful $8$-dimensional unitary representation of $\mathrm{SU}(8)$?

Comment: The way I'd give a careful proof is to look at the Weyl Dimension Formula and check that the only representations of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ of dimension $\leq 8$ are the trivial rep and the three representations related by triality. I will admit I haven't done this, although I don't think it will be hard.

Comment: Am I correct to summarize your answer that Spin(N) $\subset SU(N)$ for $N \leq 6$, but Spin(N) $\not \subset SU(N)$  for $N \geq 7$? thanks! (voted +1)

Comment: @anniemariecœur Yes -- except that I didn't do the check mentioned in the conversation with LSpice above.

Comment: dear all of you, (1) can you also confirm whether $(8) \supset (8)$ or  (8)⊅(8) ? thanks!

Comment: (2) Please see a related post of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4216056/955245 --- Relation between the (8), (8), and (8)