# The normalizer of $\operatorname{Spin}(2N)$ in $\operatorname{U}(2^{N-1})$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, spin-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$ I can show that
$$
\U(2^{N-1})\supset \Spin(2N)
$$
when $2N > 4$ or a positive integer $N > 2$, so $\Spin(2N)$ can be embedded in $\U(2^{N-1})$.

### Question

- My question is what is the [normalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of $\Spin(2N)$ in $G=\U(2^{N-1})$?
- I want to find the maximal set of $g \in G= \U(2^{N-1})$ such that $g$ satisfies
  $$
  g n g^{-1} = n' 
  $$
  for *any* $n \in \Spin(2N)$, and there must be some $n'\in \Spin(2N)$.

Here are some examples (one is solved, two left for us to test),

1. $\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\U(4) \supset \Spin(6) = \SU(4)$. Since $\SU(4)$ is the kernel of the determinant map
   $\U(4) \to \U(1)$, so $\SU(4)$ is normal in $\U(4)$ and
   "the normalizer of $\Spin(6)=\SU(4)$ in $\U(4)$ is $\U(4)$."
2. $\U(8) \not \supset \Spin(8)$, but we can still ask the normalizer of $\Spin(8)$ in other alternative groups? [You are welcome to modify this question to appropriate...]
3. $\U(16) \supset  \Spin(10)$, the normalizer of $\Spin(10)$ in $\U(16)$ is …?

I am especially concerned about the full group structures including the finite group sectors to be included in the normalizer (thus, much more than and not just the local Lie algebra).

Comment: You state two questions, but the second one seems like the definition of the first; what is the difference?  You also give examples, but, aside from your first, solved, example, it's not clear what these illustrate except the values of $2N$ and $2^{N - 1}$ for $N = 4$ and $N = 5$, since you don't state partial results or conjecture an answer.

Comment: You also mention that you are interested in more than the Lie algebra of the normaliser (I think 'local' there is redundant).  Do you know the Lie algebra of the normaliser?

Comment: There is a minor error in the OP's question.  When $N$ is even, the semi-spinor representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(2N)$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2^{N-1}}$ is *not* faithful.  (This is clear when $N=2$, where the kernel is a copy of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, but even when $N>2$ (and $N$ is even) the semi-spinor representation has a kernel isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks very much, I found this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295711/is-spinn-a-subgroup-of-sun, I shall fix the question by U(8) $\not \supset$ Spin(8).

Comment: @Robert Bryant, could you help to modify my Spin(8) example to appropriate? Should I consider any other unitary group to embed Spin(8)? Thank you!

Comment: @wonderich:  The careful list of where each of the spin groups is actually embedded is in Harvey's book, as well as the subgroups that Harvey calls the 'classical companions'.  I think I know how to formulate your questions, but maybe you should explain what it really is that you want to know.

Comment: I have added an explicit description of each of the embeddings of the $\mathrm{Spin}(2n)$ groups you wanted to study and indicated what the normalizers are.  I believe that this answers your original questions.  Is there anything else you wanted to know?  If not, and you are satisfied with my answer, it would be good for you to accept it so that your question won't continue to come up as open.  That won't prevent other people from adding answers of their own, it just clarifies the status of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can work out the answers to these questions using the material in Chapter 11 of the book *Spinors and Calibrations* by F. Reese Harvey.  You will also need to recall that, for $N\not=4$, the group of automorphisms of $\mathrm{Spin}(2N)$ is $\mathrm{O}(2N)$ rather than $\mathrm{SO}(2N)$.  The answers depend to some extent on $N$ modulo $4$.

The point is that $\mathrm{Spin}(2N)$ is represented in $\mathbb{C}^{2^{N-1}}$ as either the full spinor space (when $N$ is odd) or a semi-spinor space (when $N$ is even), and the commuting ring of this representation (which may include complex conjugation) depends on $N$ modulo $4$.

For example, when $N=4$, the representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ is actually the complexification of a 8-dimensional real representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$, whose image in $\mathrm{O}(8)$ is just a double cover onto $\mathrm{SO}(8)$.  (In particular, this semi-spinor representation is not faithful.)  Thus, for clarity, let me call the image of this representation $\mathrm{SO}'(8)\subset\mathrm{O}(8)\subset\mathrm{U}(8)$.  The normalizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8)$ in $\mathrm{O}(8)$ is $\mathrm{O}(8)$, and conjugation by elements of $\mathrm{O}(8)$ induce all of the automorphisms of $\mathrm{SO}'(8)\simeq \mathrm{SO}(8)$.  Noting that the centralizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8)$ in $\mathrm{U}(8)$ is simply $S^1 = \{\lambda I_8 \ |\ |\lambda|^2=1\ \}$, it now follows easily that the normalizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8)$ in $\mathrm{U}(8)$ is simply $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{O}(8)$, which has two components.

Meanwhile, when $N=5$, the group $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ embeds into $\mathrm{SU}(16)$ and this irreducible representation on $\mathbb{C}^{16}$ is *not* the complexification of a 16-dimensional real representation.  Moreover, the conjugate representation on $\mathbb{C}^{16}$ is not isomorphic (as a complex representation) to the given representation.  In particular, an element of the normalizer of $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ in $\mathrm{SU}(16)$ can only induce an inner automorphism of $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$.  Meanwhile, the centralizer of $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ in $\mathrm{U}(16)$ is $S^1$, the multiples of the identity.  Thus, the normalizer of $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ in $\mathrm{U}(16)$ is $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{Spin}(10)$, which is connected.

In general, here is some information about the spin representations that can be gleaned from Harvey's book:

1. For $n>0$, the spin representation $\rho:\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\to\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$ is faithful and irreducible (even as a real representation). Moreover, the center of $\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$, is mapped under $\rho$ to $\{\,\lambda I_{2^{2n}}\ |\ \lambda^4 = 1\,\}$, which lies in the center of $\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$.  In particular, if $N\subset \mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$ is the normalizer of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$ in $\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$ then conjugation by an element $g\in N$ is the identity on the center of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$, so it represents an inner automorphism of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$ and hence can be written in the form $g = \rho(h)z$, for some $h\in\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)$ and some $z\in\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$ that lies in the centralizer of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$.  Because the representation $\rho$ is irreducible, this centralizer must be a multiple of the identity, i.e., $z = \lambda I_{2^{2n}}$ where $\lambda^{2^{2n}} = 1$.  Thus, $N$ is the product in $\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$ of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$ with the center of $\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$.  In particular, it follows that the normalizer of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$ in $\mathrm{U}(2^{2n})$ is the product of $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\bigr)$ with the center of $\mathrm{U}(2^{2n})$, a group isomorphic to $S^1$.  In particular, the normalizer in the full unitary group is connected.
2. For $n>0$, the spin representation $\rho = (\rho_+,\rho_-):\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\to\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})\times\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$
   is faithful, but each of the semi-spin representations $\rho_\pm:\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\to\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$, while irreducible (even as a real representation), is a double cover onto its image in $\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$.  In fact, the center of $\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ in such a way that the kernel of $\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\to \mathrm{SO}(8n{+}4)$ is $\{(\pm 1,\pm1)\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, while the kernel of $\rho_+$ is $\{(\pm 1,1)\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the kernel of $\rho_-$ is $\{(1,\pm1)\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.  I don't know a universally agreed-on notation, but some writers use $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)\subset\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ for $\rho_+\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\bigr)$ and $\mathrm{SO}''(8n{+}4)\subset\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ for $\rho_-\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\bigr)$.  It is important to note that neither $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$ nor $\mathrm{SO}''(8n{+}4)$ have outer automorphisms.  Consequently, the normalizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$ in $\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ consists of the product of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$ with its centralizer in $\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$.  But, since $\rho_+$ is irreducible as a real representation, its centralizer in $\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n+2})$ is $\mathrm{Sp}(1)$, of which, only its center lies in $\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ and hence in $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$.  Thus, the normalizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$ in $\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ is just $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$ itself.  From this information, it is now easy to determine the normalizers of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)$ in the larger groups $\mathrm{U}(2^{4n+1})$ and $\mathrm{O}(2^{4n+2})$.  The story for $\mathrm{SO}''(8n{+}4)$ is similar.
3. For $n>0$, the spin representation $\rho = (\rho_+,\rho_-):\mathrm{Spin}(8n)\to\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})\times\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$
   is faithful, but each of the semi-spin representations $\rho_\pm:\mathrm{Spin}(8n)\to\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$, while irreducible with commuting ring $\mathbb{R}$, is a double cover onto its image in $\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$.  In fact, the center of $\mathrm{Spin}(8n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ in such a way that the kernel of $\mathrm{Spin}(8n)\to \mathrm{SO}(8n)$ is $\{(\pm 1,\pm1)\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, while the kernel of $\rho_+$ is $\{(\pm 1,1)\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the kernel of $\rho_-$ is $\{(1,\pm1)\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Again, I don't know a universally agreed-on notation, but some writers use $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)\subset\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$ for $\rho_+\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(8n)\bigr)$ and $\mathrm{SO}''(8n)\subset\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$ for $\rho_-\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(8n)\bigr)$.  When $n>1$, neither $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)$ nor $\mathrm{SO}''(8n)$ have outer automorphisms.  Consequently, the normalizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)$ in $\mathrm{O}(2^{4n-1})$ consists of the product of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)$ with its centralizer in $\mathrm{O}(2^{4n-1})$.  But, since $\rho_+$ is irreducible with commmuting ring $\mathbb{R}$, its centralizer in $\mathrm{O}(2^{4n-1})$ is $\pm 1$ times the identity, which already lies in $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)$.  Thus, the normalizer of $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)$ in $\mathrm{O}(2^{4n-1})$ is just $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)$ itself. The story for $\mathrm{SO}''(8n{+}4)$ is similar.  Finally, when $n=1$, it turns out that $\mathrm{SO}'(8)\simeq \mathrm{SO}''(8)\simeq \mathrm{SO}(8)$ (because of triality), so these groups do have outer automorphisms, and so the normalizer of these groups in $\mathrm{O}(8)$ is $\mathrm{O}(8)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! (voted up.) May I make sure is the normalizer of $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ in $\mathrm{U}(16)$ is $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ or $\frac{\mathrm{U}(1) \times \mathrm{Spin}(10)}{{\mathbb{Z}/4}}$? Since that $\mathrm{U}(1)=S^1$ and it may share the discrete $\mathbb{Z}/4$ with the center of $Z(\mathrm{Spin}(10))=\mathbb{Z}/4$? How can we make sure the discrete factors?

Comment: @wonderich:  Well, the notation $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ *means* the group generated by the two commuting groups.  In fact, the intersection of the two groups is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_4$, so what I wrote is the same as what you wrote as $\bigl(\mathrm{U}(1)\times\mathrm{Spin}(10)\bigr)/\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: Thanks! How about $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{O}(8)$? It should at least contain the $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$? Note that the center $Z(\mathrm{Spin}(8))=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, the center $Z(\mathrm{O}(8))=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Is that precisely $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{O}(8)$ given by $\frac{S^1 \times \mathrm{O}(8) }{\mathbb{Z}_2}$? Or should $S^1$ acts on the $ \mathrm{O}(8)$ like a semi-direct product? Otherwise, how does this $S^1{\cdot}\mathrm{O}(8)$ contain a $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ really?

Comment: @wonderich:  Maybe what I wrote above wasn't clear. *$\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ is not a subgroup of $\mathrm{U}(8)$*. There is an embedding of $\mathrm{Spin(8)}$ into $\mathrm{SO}(8)\times\mathrm{SO}(8)$, but the commuting ring of this subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(16)$ is $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{C}$.  The semi-spinor representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ on $\mathbb{C}^8$ is not faithful, but is $2$-to-$1$, and its image is a copy of $\mathrm{SO}(8)\subset\mathrm{U}(8)$.  The intersection of $\mathrm{O}(8)\subset\mathrm{U}(8)$ with $S^1$ is $\{\pm I_8\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: maybe you also know the answer? many thanks! mathoverflow.net/questions/384647